# vim/gvim can not highlight .svh/.sv/.txt file automatically

Tags: vim, editor, soc

I would like to use vim/gvim to automatically highlight my code file for example .svh/.sv/.txt file and here is my setting picture:

[image: set file of .vimrc]

and i source it. But it always failed to automatically highlight the code file.

fix that error with some ways

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if Vim does not support verilog files out of the box. You will need to install a plugin (or write one yourself) to make it work.

A quick search found the [verilog systemverilog](https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim) plugin. You might give it a try. I have no experience with it but it seems to be actively maintained.

The plugin will work for `*.v,*.vh,*.vp,*.sv,*.svi,*.svh,*.svp,*.sva` files.
I would not recommend to also use it for `*.txt` files as this will affect all plain text files.

Comment: it did not work. just shows error detected while processing vim +PlugInstall +qall

Comment: Did you install a plugin manager ([vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) or [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)) first?

Comment: yes I first add plugin in the vimrc and then commend this line. I think from a server I can not plugin cause I do not have any access.

Comment: Plug 'vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim' I add this in vimrc and then run this code vim +PlugInstall +qall

Comment: If you chose to do it without a plugin manager, you don't need to run `PlugInstall`. This would make the manager install the plugins. You don't have a manger and you cannot install. Don't call it! Just make sure you have all the files in the right places. This is on your machine, I won't be able to help you there.

Comment: yes but my other colleagues can use vim to automatically highlight it. so there should be some ways without plugin

Comment: Then my answer obviously will not help you. I would suggest you ask your colleagues how they made it work. Please post an answer once you figure something out that works for you.

Comment: they are busy I do not have a chance to ask....

Comment: Give me their number, I will call and ask them on your behalf :)